# htaccess rewriting address bar

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have been trying to change my urls to make them more SEO friendly
and at the moment have managed to get them sort of working how
I want it.

My original url is this:
http://www.example.com/index.php?keyword=nikon

So managed to get this rewriting so that it now looks like this:

http://www.example.com/compare/nikon.html

Using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^compare/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?keyword=$1 [R,NC,L]
```

But I have tried to get the end result so that the url in the address bar 
is like this: http://www.example.com/compare/nikon.html

If I change it so that the rewritten url is in the address bar will the 
variables still be passed and in instances where there is an anchor # tag 
after the url will it still work?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get rid of the `R` flag in your rule. That's causing the address bar to be changed to the original ugly looking URL.

Additionally, if you want to redirect the browser from the ugly to the nicer looking URL, you need a different rule. So something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?keyword=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /compare/%1.html? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^compare/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?keyword=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help but when I try the above it it rewrites the url in the address bar but doesn't add the .html bit

Comment: @OLM256 Nah, I forgot to add it to the rule, see the edit above

Comment: thanks Jon - it's now adding the .html bit but then is page not found

Comment: Tried to tweak your code but not getting anywhere really - the url's rewrite ok now just that it doesn't find page so looks like something is not being passed through??

Comment: @OLM256 is there another htaccess file somewhere? Are there other rules?

Comment: There are other rules but for testing I started with a clean file and just the code above. Will check the landing page just in case there is something in there causing an issue

Comment: Hi again - so nearly there now - it's working but now the css and other files files are not found - probably as they are referenced like this: "assets/themes/" instead of "/assets/themes/" - is there anything that can be done in .htaccess so as to avoid going through all the files??

Comment: Also sorry can this be restricted to the index in the root - right now it affects any index including in subdirectories. Thanks for your help and sorry for the questions

Comment: Thanks sorted it now - relative urls added <base href="http://example.com" /> to the head and all fixed now. Thanks for your help